# Oracle conditional select based on address type

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm working on a query to get student contact mailing addresses, and am at point where I am a bit stuck. I have managed to get a list of all student, and their contacts, but now when i try and join the contacts to their addresses, i'm not exactly sure how to get the correct address.

In the address table can hold multiple kinds of addresses (Home, Mailing, Business, Pickup, Dropoff) and basically what i need to do is only bring back one address per contact.

Normally this would be the home address, unless there is a mailing address

So my question is how do i write some type of conditional statement to only get entries WHERE ADDRESS_TYPE_NAME = 'Home' unless there is also an entry WHERE ADDRESS_TYPE_NAME = 'Mailing' for the same PERSON_ID?

Thanks

Comment: Please add your sample input and expected output

Comment: Can a student have more than one home address (or more than one mailing address)? If so, what should be selected? Also, it is guaranteed that every student will have at least one address that is either home or mailing? If not, what should be shown for that student?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with CTE as
(
select Person_id, 
       Address_Type_Name,
       Address_Info -- replace with your real column names
from Address_Table
where Address_Type_Name in ('Home','Mailing')
)
select Person_id, Address_info
from CTE  a1
where Address_Type_Name = 'Home'
and not exists (select 1 
                from CTE a2 
                where a2.Address_Type_Name = 'Mailing'
                and a2.Person_id = a1.Person_id)
union 
select Person_id, Address_info
from CTE  a1
where Address_Type_Name = 'Mailing'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prioritize Address Type  and get highest priority type  with

```
select Person_id, 
   case min(case Address_Type_Name
             when 'Mailing' then 1
             when 'Home'  then 2 
             -- more
            end) 
       when 1 then 'Mailing'
       when 2 then 'Home' 
       -- more
   end Best_Address_Type_Name
from Address_Table
group by Person_id;
```

Then join the result to your data as needed

Comment: Why join instead of using the group_by you already have? Add a column for the address itself (you may need to use `keep (dense_rank first/last order by <the same thing you already have>)`).

Comment: @mathguy I agree it may be directly the the result OP wants. Or it may be a part of more complex query, don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, using the `row_number()` analytic function and not requiring any joins, explicit or implicit. It also handles various special cases: a student who has neither mailing nor home address (but still needs to be shown in the output), and another student with two mailing addresses (in which case a random one is chosen; if there are criteria to prefer one to the other, the query can be easily adapted to accommodate that).

```
with
     students ( id, name, address_type, address ) as (
       select 11, 'Andy', 'home'   , '123 X street'   from dual union all
       select 11, 'Andy', 'office' , 'somewhere else' from dual union all
       select 15, 'Eva' , 'mailing', 'post office'    from dual union all
       select 18, 'Jim' , 'office' , '1 building'     from dual union all
       select 30, 'Mary', 'mailing', 'mail addr 1'    from dual union all
       select 30, 'Mary', 'office' , '1 building'     from dual union all
       select 30, 'Mary', 'home'   , 'her home'       from dual union all
       select 30, 'Mary', 'mailing', 'mail addr 2'    from dual
     )
--  End of test data (not needed for the SQL query - reference your actual table)
select id, name, address_type, 
       case when address_type is not null then address end as address
from   (
         select id, name, 
                    case when address_type in ('home', 'mailing') 
                         then address_type end as address_type,
                    address,
                    row_number() over (partition by id 
                          order by case address_type when 'mailing' then 0
                                                     when 'home'    then 1 end) as rn
          from students
       )
where rn = 1
;

 ID NAME ADDRESS_TYPE ADDRESS
--- ---- ------------ --------------
 11 Andy home         123 X street
 15 Eva  mailing      post office
 18 Jim
 30 Mary mailing      mail addr 1

4 rows selected.
```